# how to clear asp output cache manually from the server side

Tags: asp.net, caching, browser-cache

i have setup a cache but would like to clear it manualy from the server side but not sure how you do that.  i have tried to recycle the app pool but that only cleared the cache from my development server and not the production.  I can see the old values on the browser.

Comment: What cache are you referring to? Session, View State, ASP.NET output caching, etc.

Comment: sorry output caching...

Comment: I'm confused...just recycle the app pool on the production server.